# QString split return list of empty strings

Tags: c++, regex, qt4

Using this regex `B([^.]*)E` I am trying to get all the characters between `B` and `E` from

```
B23432|234|24EB23432|2834|234EB23432|2134|234E
```

Using Qt4.8

```
QRegExp rx("B([^.]*)E");
rx.setMinimal(true);
QString str = "B23432|234|24EB23432|2834|234EB23432|2134|234E";
QStringList list;
list = str.split(rx);
qDebug() << list;
```

it prints a list of empty strings. Shouldn't it return all the strings between `B` and `E`?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the characters between the B and the first E or the E at the very end of the line?

Comment: `[^.]` will not match any character. You can try what @stribizhev suggested or `B(.*)E`.

Comment: No, just something like `("23432|234|24", "23432|2834|234", "23432|2134|234") `  I think that the code is to blame rather than the expression. On regex101.com [https://regex101.com/r/dL0tJ2/1] both expressions function as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to split, but in fact you need to find all matches in a loop and get `capturedTexts()[1]`s (or `cap(1)`s).

```
QRegExp rx("B([^E]*)E");
rx.setMinimal(true);
QString str = "B23432|234|24EB23432|2834|234EB23432|2134|234E";
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
qDebug() << list;
```

Comment: Just an afterthought: perhaps, you could use a [split with `B|E` regex](https://regex101.com/r/mT2sW5/1), but you would have empty elements in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well. If there is something wrong with this please let me know.

```
QRegExp rx("[B(.*)E]");
rx.setMinimal(true);
QString str = "B23432|234|24EB23432|2834|234EB23432|2134|234E";
QStringList list;
list = str.split(rx, QString::SkipEmptyParts);
qDebug() << list;
```

Comment: @Vlad I thought I would use this as an opportunity to learn to use QBENCHMARK` and here is what the results are. test1 is stribizhev's method: ```RESULT : TestBenchmark::test1():
     0.0089 msecs per iteration (total: 73, iterations: 8192)```
```RESULT : TestBenchmark::test2():
     0.035 msecs per iteration (total: 73, iterations: 2048)```